# Convert PCRE2 to Extended POSIX RE, do I really require lazy?

Tags: regex, posix, regex-greedy, posix-ere

I have written the following regex:

```
^project\(.+?version\s*:\s*'(.+?)'.*\)$
```

The first capture group will grab `0.9.20` from the following block of text:

```
project(
    'waybar', 'cpp', 'c',
    version: '0.9.20',
    license: 'MIT',
    meson_version: '>= 0.50.0',
    default_options : [
        'cpp_std=c++20',
        'buildtype=release',
        'default_library=static'
    ],
)
```

https://regex101.com/r/ycMSeh/1

I need this regex to be compatible with Extended POSIX regular expression syntax.

My best attempt is this:

```
^project\([^)]*version[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*'\([^']*\)'.*\)$
```

However, that means the capture group matches `>= 0.50.0` instead of `0.9.20`.  The pattern `[^)]*` is not specific enough, and POSIX ERE does not have a lazy operator, `?`, which means that it consumes until the line that starts with `meson_version`.

Comment: How about trying `^project\(\n\s+[^\n]+\n\s+version:\s+'([^']+)',\n`  **or** `^project\(\n\s+[^\n]+\n\s+version:\s+'([^']+)',` once? Using multiline option in regex101 site, here is the demo for same https://regex101.com/r/w3aQPr/1

Comment: How about: [https://regex101.com/r/uVYiya/1](https://regex101.com/r/uVYiya/1)